# How to upgrade bootstrap 4 to bootstrap 5? - YARN

Tags: bootstrap-4, yarnpkg, bootstrap-5

How can I upgrade Bootstrap 4 installed using Yarn to Bootstrap 5?

Comment: See [`yarn upgrade`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/).

Comment: @AKX this will upgrade all packages in my project, I can't use yarn upgrade.

Comment: `yarn upgrade bootstrap`?

Comment: @AKX nothing happened it's still "bootstrap": "4.6.0"

Comment: `yarn upgrade bootstrap --latest`? :)

Comment: @AKX Great, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`yarn upgrade`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/) command has a `--latest` switch:

> The `upgrade --latest` command upgrades packages the same as the upgrade command, but ignores the version range specified in package.json. Instead, the version specified by the latest tag will be used (potentially upgrading the packages across major versions).

In other words,

> `yarn upgrade bootstrap --latest`

will bump the version of the `bootstrap` package to whatever is the latest version available.